# Iterator (Iterate Feature Selection) running loop in undesired path using ArcMap ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator, loop

I am building a model using Iterate Feature Selection. I want to run the Iterator -> select by location -> Calculate field, and after finishing this loop (#3 in the image below), I will continue to the next process (#4 in the image below).

[image]

But when I run the model, it go to the next process until the end, then come to start the next loop, repeatedly.

[image]

Comment: You want to but the iterator component and any thing that will loop with it in a SUB model. So you have models within a model. Golden rule is that EVERYTHING in a model with an iterator will run as many time as the iterator loops. Check out this site and the help file on sub-models.